# .htaccess refuse open index.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a .htaccess file like this :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and route like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index',[
        'bg' => 'bg-nayapink',
        'active' =>'Home'
    ]);
});

Route::get('/services', function () {
    return view('services', [
        'active' => 'Services',
        'bg' => 'bg-nayayellow'
    ]);
});
```

The problem is that whenever I tried to access "mysite.com" (mean: '/' route) it always opened index.html instead of index.php. Other routes are open normally, except the empty one. The website is already hosted on a shared server.

Comment: In which order index files are used is also depended on the webserver's settings. Edit the server configuration - or why not delete the `index.html` then? Is this on shared webhosting? Maybe a custom `.htaccess` isn't allowed?

Comment: there's no index.html, so it just display 404, and for .htaccess is allowed. I have checked. I left the setting on default and if I'm not wrong it's already on index.php

Comment: If the default was `index.php` then it would not open `index.html` as you wrote. And is `mod_rewrite` also activated? You can check by removing the IfModule tags.

Comment: that `mod_rewrite` is from the .htaccess from the laravel (default). And I've recheck the server setting, and it has:
`$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';`

is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: And recently I found that if I open with `mysite.com//` it opens that index.php.

Comment: It fixed. Apparently, there is a website already that has been deleted and then overwritten to this one. I just need the clear all cache. Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It is because of the cache. Before this site, there was a site too already and has been deleted then overwritten with this one. So, I just need to clear all cache.